# Vue v-for loop added input field, types on same value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

My View

```
<div v-for="(listings, index) in list2" :key="index">
  <b-form-input id="input-live" v-model="listings.first_name" placeholder="PLAYER NAME 1" disabled></b-form-input>
  <b-form-input id="input-live" v-model="rfidSideA"></b-form-input>
</div>

/** prints out three field for first_name and rfidSideA as I want **/
/** BUT when I type value for first rfidSideA input field, it displays same on other two as well **/
```

List2 data

```
[
 {
  first_name : {"John", "David", "Dave" }
 }
]
```

**Error:**
Whatever I type on first rfidSideA input field, it displays same value for other two field generated as well.

Is there a way to type different value for rfidSideA input field and pass it to data return using method?

Comment: This is easy to resolve. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) and others can help more.

Comment: How is your rfidSideA defined

Comment: `first_name : {"John", "David", "Dave" }`  this is invalid syntax. Is `first_name` meant to be an array or an object?

Comment: @PrabhatGupta its not defined. I am trying to pass data through that field on data() {return { rfidSideA: ' ' } }

Comment: Just set rfidSideA like `v-model="listings.rfidSideA"`

Comment: @palaѕн yup I tried that before it worked but where can find that value in data return ? Do I have to create new array inside data() return called listings?

Comment: Its inside `list2` only.. same place where you get `first_name` invalid values..

Comment: @palaѕн i did not know it will store new value on the same list. Thank You it got solved.

Comment: But how did you know `first_name` is saved in `List2`? You were already using same logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you assign same variable to different v-model they all will be pointing to same variable. thus for each individual element assign different variable.
While in loop you need to find any value relative to loop.

```
<div v-for="(listings, index) in list2" :key="index">
  <b-form-input id="input-live" v-model="listings.first_name" placeholder="PLAYER NAME 1" disabled></b-form-input>
  <b-form-input id="input-live" v-model="listings.rfidSideA"></b-form-input>
</div>
```